# How to remove black screen on windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form.

In that form I have loaded a panel.

When I resize the form the non client area becomes black.

How to remove the black screen.

I have tried in many ways like passing parameter, double buffer.

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you doing anything special? can you reproduce with a new project?

Comment: Maybe example of picture? I can't imagine it.

Comment: Some controls have a DoubleBuffered property too, try set them to true as well.

Comment: Are you redrawing/invalidate on resize?